# What is q.js adding that isn't in the javascript Promise implementation?

Tags: javascript, q

I am not a js dev and don't really know the history/relationship behind q.js and Promises. When I look at the Mozilla Developer Network documentation it looks to me, that the native javascript Promise implementation does more or less what q.js does. Was q.js an early implementation of promises? Do I need it today?

Now when I am working on some (4-5 year old) code that uses q.js I constantly see my call stack filled with calls to q.js, when I am adding code that I am assuming is using the native Promise implementation. I would like to remove q.js from the project, but I don't have a deep enough understanding of what value it adds to the native Promise implementation. Is it just to support Browsers without a Promise implementation? Or is there something else going on?

Comment: Native Promise support came later in time. Many "custom" promise libraries were released before that.

Comment: It would be helpful to get some more background on the current code you are working with. Typically libraries such as q help to simplify xhr calls and the handling of promises. I am myself a recent js dev as well but if I recall correctly js native promises are somewhat new and depending on the previous developers wasn't necessarily something that they adopted when it was first released. I would assume that they may have used an existing library for sake of compatibility with various browser versions. To answer the question I believe that q is simply providing an abstraction to native promises

Comment: Promise is a new feature of ES6, but before that there're a lot of solutions to deal with "hell of callback" or "pyramid of doom" issues for asynchronous programming, while q is a most famous one.  If you can guarantee that your code will not run any container (e.g., browser, node,js, etc.) that only support ES standard earlier than ES6, definitely you do so such "porting" work.

Comment: @BrettReinhard I am working on a fork of the kiwix-js project https://github.com/sharun-s/kiwix-html5 which is a offline wikipedia dump reader. So there are a lot of async reads both XHR and FileReader based. I would like to remove q.js as it would simplify all my call stacks while debugging but before doing that am trying to get a sense of the differences, specifically what it brings to the table that may not be in the native implementation.

Comment: Yes, Q was in fact the *first* promises implementation in JS. It still can be used as a library where no native implementation is available, and also provides [a host of useful helper methods](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference) that native promises don't have (but which could be trivially implemented on top of them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this option in the q.js docs, to solve the call stack issue - Q.longStackSupport = true; But after more testing I have just ended up removing q.js as the native Promise implementation was doing all that I needed.